# Customize captions

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to group the captions in the chart?
Attach an image with an example. What I wanted is, in the red line enter an enter ("\ n" or "br"). It's possible?
Thank you

Image: https://pasteboard.co/HXPlaT2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap **layoutItem** function in Highcharts.Legend.prototype and start a new line when a fake **newLine** property will be found in series options:

```
// If the item exceeds the width, start a new line
if (
  horizontal &&
  (
    this.itemX - padding + itemWidth > maxLegendWidth ||
    item.userOptions.newLine
  )
) {
  this.itemX = padding;
  this.itemY += itemMarginTop + this.lastLineHeight +
    itemMarginBottom;
  this.lastLineHeight = 0; // reset for next line (#915, #3976)
}
```

You should put this property in the series which you want to start from the new line:

```
, {
  name: 'Manufacturing1',
  data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 9031, 119931, 137133, 54175],
  newLine: true
  }
```

jsFiddle (working for v10.2.1 and lower): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zbcLeyat

Comment: You're welcome. As a bigger "thank you" you can also give an upvote ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have less than 15 reputation. That's why I can't give you upvote. 
When I get to 15 of reputation, I will give you upvote ;). Sorry

Comment: Is it possible to group multiple filters in a new filter? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? You want to group all "installation" filters into one or add the new one and keep existing ones? Could you describe it more precisely?

Comment: I want to group all "installation" filters into one, but keep all others.

Comment: You can create the new fake series (so they are displayed in the legend) and connect them to series you want to hide on click using fake "group" property. Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lh2akje1

Answer (score 0):

Since Highcharts 10.3.1 this function is broken. As a workaround I run Highcharts on 10.2.1 by changing the source script. (Also posted this on the Highcharts forum.)

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/10.2.1/highcharts.js"></script>
```